# calculate total size file input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `input` like this:

```
<input type="file" name="upload[]" class="file" />
<input type="file" name="upload[]" class="file" />
<input type="file" name="upload[]" class="file" />
<input type="file" name="upload[]" class="file" />
```

And I need to calculate `size` of all input.
I tried code's :

```
$(".file").each(function() {
   alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

OR

```
$(".file").each(function(i) {
   alert(this.files[i].size);
});
```

But this code's don't work after `index 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a loop over `this.files` as well, to grab all the files selected in a single input. `Try this:

```
$('.file').each(function(i) {
    $.each(this.files, function(i, file) {
        console.log(file.size);
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/n5wdhtpw/)

Comment: Thanks. But I need this code in `submit` method not `change`!

Comment: Then you just need to copy and paste it ;)